# Alternative usage of WAF with Load Balancer since WAF doesn't support?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer, azure-security

In my application, I needed IPv6 support for WAF. Since IPv6 yet not supported by the WAF can I use a load balancer connected to the WAF as the following diagram (because of IPv6 supports Load Balancer)? Is this a good design?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the Azure load balancer to connect to an application gateway since Azure load balancer only works with VM, VMS, or availability sets as its backend. Have a look at backend pool endpoints [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview#why-use-standard-load-balancer).

More info: [Overview of IPv6 for Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-ipv6-overview)

Comment: Thanks, Nancy, But what would be the alternative solution to connect with IPv6 endpoint to the public with WAF ?

Comment: Unfortunately, afaik, currently there is no way to do that in Azure since waf is supported in Azure app gateway but it does not support ipv6. more references [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/286a89c2-9ee4-44ff-a97e-6e945675a701/why-is-that-the-azure-web-application-firewall-doesnot-support-for-ipv6-ip-address-space-?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork).